# Is every smooth volume form induced from a Riemannian metric?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Given a nonvanishing smooth $n$-form $\omega$ on a smooth $n$-manifold $M$,
is there a Riemannian metric on $M$ whose induced volume form equals $\omega$?

Here the induced volume form for a Riemannian metric $g$ is the form given in local coordinates by $\sqrt{\mathrm{det}G}\,dx_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_n$ where $(G_{ij})_{i,j=1}^{n} $ is the symmetric matrix of real functions s.t. $g = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} G_{ij}\,dx_i \otimes dx_j$.

Would anyone have a suggestion on how to approach this?

Comment: Yes, it is a consequence of Moser's theorem (in the compact case) and Greene-Wu (in the noncompact case).

Comment: @MoisheKohan I see, thanks very much!

Comment: Let $g$ be any smooth Riemannian metric on $M$. There is a positive function $f$ such that $\omega  = f\,dV_g$. The metric $f^{2/n}g$ has the volume form $\omega$.

Comment: @Deane Oh I see, thanks very much!